# Combine multiple results into 1

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have multiple queries:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tab1;
SELECT colA, colB FROM tab2;
SELECT colTest, colBlah FROM tab3;
```

Every query would return only 1 result.

How can I combine those 3 results into 1?

The result would look like that:

```
+------+------+------+------+---------+---------+
| col1 | col2 | colA | colB | colTest | colBlah |
+------+------+------+------+---------+---------+
| abc  | def  | Ghi  | JkL  | 12A     | 42BD    |
+------+------+------+------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join them all:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.colA, t2.colB, t3.colTest, t3.colBlah
FROM tab1 AS t1
CROSS JOIN tab2 AS t2
CROSS JOIN tab3 AS t3
```

Comment: @user1170330 - (I know you said the statements only return one record, but ...) be sure you understand [how cross joins work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) when there is *more* than one record involved.

Answer (score 0):

```
select tab1.col1, tab1.col2, tab2.colA, tab2.colB, tab3.colTest, tab3.colBlah from tab1, tab2, tab3
```