# Combine multiple results with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have multiple queries:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tab1 WHERE col1 = "%abc%";
SELECT colA, colB FROM tab2 WHERE colA = "%123%" AND colB IS NOT NULL;
SELECT colTest, colBlah FROM tab3;
```

Every query would return only 1 result.

How can I combine those 3 results into 1?

The result would look like that:

```
+------+------+------+------+---------+---------+
| col1 | col2 | colA | colB | colTest | colBlah |
+------+------+------+------+---------+---------+
| abc  | def  | Ghi  | JkL  | 12A     | 42BD    |
+------+------+------+------+---------+---------+
```

As [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42349615/1170330), I could use a `cross join`. But where to put the `WHERE` conditions?
If I put them just at the end of the entire query, I would get an empty result, when only one of them fails. That's why I need to put them separately for every query.

Comment: what is the relation between the three tables?

Comment: @davejal: Actually, this is irrelevant in this example.

Comment: @user1170330 No it isn't, what are the primary key/foreign key relationships? Without these, we have no idea where to join the result sets.

Comment: cross join, works well if each select returns only 1 row.

Comment: @David: They can be joined by `ID`.

Comment: @jarlh: Yes, but how to combine the conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each query returns exactly one row (as in your example), you can do:

```
SELECT q1.col1, q1.col2, q2.colA, q2.colB, q3.colTest, q3.colBlah
FROM (SELECT col1, col2 FROM tab1 WHERE col1 = '%abc%') q1 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT colA, colB FROM tab2 WHERE colA = '%123%' AND colB IS NOT NULL) q2 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT colTest, colBlah FROM tab3) q3;
```

EDIT:

You can handle missing data (which is explicitly not the question being asked) by using `union all` and aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(col1) as col1,
       MAX(col2) as col2,
       MAX(colA) as colA,
       MAX(colB) as colB,
       MAX(colTest) as colTest,
       MAX(colBlah) as colBlah
FROM ((SELECT col1, col2, NULL as colA, NULL a colB, NULL as colTest, NULL as colBlah
       FROM tab1
       WHERE col1 = '%abc%'
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT NULL, NULL, colA, colB, NULL, NULL
       FROM tab2
       WHERE colA = '%123%' AND colB IS NOT NULL
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, colTest, colBlah
       FROM tab3
      ) 
     ) t;
```

Comment: This only works, if all conditions return true. If only 1 of them returns false, I get an empty result. Instead, the query, that returns an empty result, should just remain empty, without affecting the results of the other queries.

Comment: @user1170330 . . . "Every query would return only 1 result.".  It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.

Comment: Yes, a maximum of 1. I also can return nothing, if the conditions don't trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what the names of the id fields are for the joins but these are possibilities:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2,  t2.colA, t2.colB, t3. colTest, t3.colBlah
FROM tab1 t1
JOIN tab2 t2 On t1.tab1id = t2.tab1id
JOIN tab3 on t1.tab1id = t3.tab1id
WHERE t1.col1 = "%abc%";
            AND t2.colA = "%123%" 
            AND t2.colB IS NOT NULL;

SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2,  t2.colA, t2.colB, t3. colTest, t3.colBlah
FROM tab1 t1
LEFT JOIN tab2 t2 On t1.tab1id = t2.tab1id
LEFT JOIN tab3 on t1.tab1id = t3.tab1id
WHERE t1.col1 = "%abc%";
            AND t2.colA = "%123%" 
            AND t2.colB IS NOT NULL;
```

NOte that if you expect all three field to contain data for each record, use the first query. If there might not be data in tab2 or tab3, then the second is appropriate. If only one might not have data you only need one left join. If there might not be data in all three of teh tables, then use a full join.

Comment: This only works, if all conditions return true. If only 1 of them returns false, I get an empty result. Instead, the query, that returns an empty result, should just remain empty, without affecting the results of the other queries.

Answer (score 0):

If each query returned exactly one row , as you originally stated, then you'd cross join the rows:

```
select * from (query#1) q1 cross join (query#2) q2  cross join (query#3) q3;
```

But as the queries can actually return either zero or one rows, you'd outer join instead:

```
select * 
from (query#1) q1 
full outer join (query#2) q2 on true 
full outer join (query#3) q3 on true;
```

(An outer join requires an ON clause, which we don't actually need. So we use `ON true` here, i.e. join regardless of the records' contents.)

MySQL, however, doesn't support outer joins. So we must look for another approach. One simple way for queries that return either none or one record is aggregation:

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(col1) AS col1, ANY_VALUE(col2) AS col2 FROM tab1 WHERE col1 = "%abc%";
```

This gets exactly the same record as

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tab1 WHERE col1 = "%abc%";
```

Only that in case there is no match, it returns a row of nulls instead of no rows. Hence:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  (SELECT ANY_VALUE(col1) AS col1, ANY_VALUE(col2) AS col2
   FROM tab1 WHERE col1 = "%abc%") q1
CROSS JOIN 
  (SELECT ANY_VALUE(colA) AS colA, ANY_VALUE(colB) AS colB
   FROM tab2 WHERE colA = "%123%" AND colB IS NOT NULL) q2
CROSS JOIN 
  (SELECT ANY_VALUE(colTest) AS colTest, ANY_VALUE(colBlah) AS colBlah 
   FROM tab3) q3;
```